# Is it possible to extend a class from __init__.py

Tags: python, pandas, python-import, class-extensions

I have written a small python package which extends a pandas dataframe with a few additional methods.

At the moment, I have this code in my package:

```
def init():
    @pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("test")
    class _:
        def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
            self._obj = pandas_obj

        def myMethod(self):
            pass
```

I then do the following in python:

```
import pandas as pd
import mypackage as mp
mp.init()
test = pd.Dataframe(<define data frame>)
test.mp.myMethod()
```

My question is, is it possible to do the pandas import and register the accessor from within the `__init__.py` in mypackage, so that once mypackage is imported, I automatically have access to mymethod without the init() step? My current approach feels a bit clunky...

Comment: You can do what ever's necessary in the `__init__.py` to initialize the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be missing something in your question, but I think you might be barking up the wrong tree.  There's nothing special about `__init__.py` in this regard--anything you write in `__init__.py` is executed when you import the package, so I don't think you need that `init()` function at all.  If you have a file containing:

```
# mypackage/__init__.py
import pandas as pd


@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("test")
class _:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self._obj = pandas_obj

    def myMethod(self):
        print(self._obj)
```

Now you can just use it by importing `mypackage` like:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import mypackage
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]})
>>> df.test.myMethod()
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

As an aside, one reason you might explicitly *want* something like your `init()` function is principle of least surprise: Since `register_dataframe_accessor` modifies the namespace of `DataFrame` instances for all users (including other libraries) there is a small possibility that your `register_dataframe_accessor`, just by importing your package, might override some other package's dataframe acccessor if they happen to share the same name.

If the name is reasonably unique this may not be a problem though.  It also may simply not be a problem for your package depending on how it's intended to be used.